# Update in DB2 using where exists instead of join

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I'm trying to perform an update in DB2, which I started out trying with an inner join, but DB2 won't allow that. I altered it to use a 'where exists' clause but now it's telling me that `main_discount` in my `set` clause is not found (I'm assuming because it isn't referenced until the later `where exists`

How can I make this work as expected if I don't yet have the column value I need?

```
update main_library.details
set less_amount = ROUND(cast (price as float) * (main_discount/100),2)
    where exists(
        select 
               price,
               wholesale_num,
               main_discount,
               startDate,
               endDate
        from main_library.details D
            inner join 2nd_library.discounts DISC
                on D.wholesale_num = DISC.wholesale_num
            where wholesale_num  = 123
    )
limit 200;
```

Comment: Please tag your question with a more precise tag : db2-400, db2-luw or db2-zos. Not the same answer.

Comment: @nfgl ah, sorry about that. It's db2-400, I just updated the tag now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DB2 for i does not allow the UPDATE table FROM that DB2LUW allows

You have two solutions

One is [UPDATE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-update) using one subquery to select the rows to update, and another to get the value of main_discount

```
update main_library.details as main
set less_amount = ROUND(cast (price as float) * (
   (select main_discount from 2nd_library.discounts DISC
            where wholesale_num  = main.wholesale_num)
  /100),2)
    where exists(
        select 0 from 2nd_library.discounts DISC
            where wholesale_num  = main.wholesale_num
    )
```

the other is [MERGE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-merge)

```
MERGE INTO main_library.details main
using(
select wholesale_num, main_discount from 2nd_library.discounts DISC
) disc on disc.wholesale_num = main.wholesale_num
when matched then
  update set less_amount = ROUND(cast (price as float) * (main_discount)/100),2)
```

Maybe you should use DECFLOAT rather than FLOAT to avoid suprises

Comment: Ok The first option there seemed to get me what I needed, I appreciate it. I'm also using DECFLOAT now just to be safe, thanks again!